# How do I send a file by Bluetooth from Android smartphone to an iMac running OS X Lion?

Tags: bluetooth, android

I am unsuccessfully sending a file from my smartphone Huawei Ideos X5 with Android 2.3.5 to my iMac. I paired the devices successfully. Android phone receives successfully anything from iMac, but iMac cannot receive anything. I disabled my firewall and disabled the stealth mode too but still problem persists.

**How can you make iMac able to receive a file by Bluetooth from Android smartphone?**

Comment: Tell us more about your Android phone. Model, OS Version, etc.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini It is Huawei Ideos X5 with Android 2.3. - The problem is probably with Mac and its support with Android devices.

Comment: Exact Android version 2.3.5, the official release.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Provided you have done what Vlad said (enable the Bluetooth sharing) and paired the devices (which you seem to have done), I have absolutely no problem to send files via bluetooth using my Nexus-S. I have ICS 4.03 now, but I had 2.3.x (where X is 3, 4, 5 and 6 if I'm not mistaken).

Once you have the devices Paired, if the Mac is in range and with BT enabled, the phone can send files because the Mac should be on the phone's list of paired devices. I recall that in 2.3.x sometimes it won't work, but retrying to turning on/off BT was usually enough. I don't use it a lot, but I just tried (after months of probably never touching bluetooth on either device) and I got this:

[image]

Here's my preference pane:

[image]

and Finally, this is my Phone's paired list (two are intentionally blurred), but you can see my Macbook Air:

[image]

Hope you can double-check your settings.

For reference:

1. I have Firewall ON
2. I have Firewall Stealth ON.

Here's my Firewall Screen (app list blurred by me):

[image]

Comment: I found that turning bluetooth off and on again on both devices got file transfer to work.

Comment: Great answer! I only needed to check that **Bluetooth Sharing** to get it working. :)

Comment: Not working with M1 MBA Sonoma and Redmi 10C Android 13. Firewall is off. Devices are paired. Can send from Mac to phone but the other direction silently does nothing.

Comment: I stopped using Apple products in 2018, so I can no longer help you here. Sorry!

Answer (score 21):

You need to enable Bluetooth Sharing. Go to System Preferences > Bluetooth > Sharing Setup... > check Bluetooth Sharing.

Comment: On my MacBook Air running Sierra there is no "Sharing Setup" in "System Preferences > Bluetooth".